# NGINX config rules needed

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

For a specific application I need to move from Apache to Ngninx for better scalability. Unfortunately I'm not able to convert the config to Nnginx.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(tool|web|files)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*)\.(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php?route=/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(img|css|js)/(.*) web/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Al requests should go trough dispatcher.php (if I understand right). So I tried to use the Magento Mage rule, but without success. Because I'm missing the 'basic' knowledge of Apache and Nginx it's almost impossible for me to make this configuration working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a script/config-writing service.

Comment: Just a question... And I think it's never wrong to help someone.

Comment: The problem is that there are [endless permutations of the same question](http://serverfault.com/search?q=convert+apache+to+nginx+rewrite) - it's of no value to future visitors to keep answering the same question over and over, and it's not like you've put a lot of effort into your question to motivate others to help you. If you want a solution _try something_. "Here's my nginx config, I'm trying to match this old apache config and it's doing x not y" is something people are willing to put time into to help you. "Give me the codez" questions are not well received.

Comment: @AD7six I understand your opinion. The fact is that I'm already breaking my mind for days :-D

Answer (score 1):

Use the information here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
You'll learn a lot more doing that than you would by getting other people to do it for you, and you'll be able to use what you learned if anything goes wrong or you need to change something.

Edit: Also, I wouldn't think about it in terms of converting from Apache to Nginx. Just forget about Apache, read the Nginx documentation, and start from scratch with a new configuration file.

Comment: Because  I'm missing the basics, it's  impossible for me to convert. In the past I only used Wordpress and Magento configs (easy to Google)